# ISOLINUX Live Boot Disk - Running Scripts from the Menu

Tags: linux, bootable

I am trying to create a Linux Boot Disk (i have chosen Fennix due to the small size and terminal only interface), now I have the boot disk working and it loads me into Linux and I can mount the internal HDD etc. so all good there, however I have the Menu working through ISOLINUX.CFG but I want to attach a script to each menu selection, the script will copy 2 files to the HDD from the Live disk, I am struggling to get the Menu to launch the scripts with init= as it never seems to find the script files on the disk (im not sure where to place them to get access to them, tried multiple directories).

Example Menu Option Below

LABEL finnix

MENU LABEL Install Update

TEXT HELP

Copies the 2 ini files to your Hard drive

ENDTEXT

KERNEL boot/x86/linux init=copy1.bs

APPEND initrd=boot/x86/initrd.xz vga=791 nomodeset quiet

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to access the files from the LiveCD once booted and how the menu can be updated to access these script files when a selection has been made.

Hope the above makes sense,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `isolinux.cfg`, the boot options go to the APPEND line, not to the KERNEL line. So your `init=copy1.bs` should go to the APPEND line instead.

And if you use the `init=` option, it means running your shell script as process #1: instead of setting up the regular environment with e.g. multiple virtual consoles, it will only run that one script... and once that script exits, the kernel will panic (= crash) as process #1 died.

Depending on how exactly the Finnix initrd file is constructed, using the `init=` option might also start your scripts in a situation where they would need to duplicate some or all of the functionality of the Finnix start-up scripts before they can actually do anything useful.

You might want to invent your own custom boot parameter instead. The boot parameters will appear in `/proc/cmdline` even if they are unknown to the kernel, and you can just make a start-up script that reads `/proc/cmdline`, picks your custom parameter value from there, and then uses it to execute another script at a location of your choice. This approach might be easier to debug than using the standard `init=` parameter.

The Finnix root filesystem appears to be inside the `finnix/arch/x86/root.img` file. I don't have the time to fully analyze it right now, but I'd guess the `initrd.xz` sets up a RAM disk and loads the contents of the `root.img` in there, so that the CD can be ejected while using Finnix.

To get your scripts inside the `root.img` file, you would mount the image file (it's a squashfs filesystem image), copy the contents to some other directory, add your own files into it, then use the `mksquashfs` command (in `squashfs-tools` package) to create a new image file.